# Run a long loop every time text changes

Tags: jquery

I have a table which has some empty textboxes. When the user enters value, the subtotal and total should change in real time. However my code is not working.

Here's an attempt [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jht5j/)

```
$rows.each(function(index) {
            $rows.children("td").each(function() { 
                qty = $("td:nth-child(2) input").val();
                rate = $("td:nth-child(3) input").val();
                amount = qty * rate;
                subtotal = amount;

            });
});
```

Also how to make this **work with performance for a large table.**

Comment: I'm assuming you mean to bind to keyboard events..as the user types you want the total to update. You need to bind your update function to the 'onkeyup'event. This .each function is only running once on load, but it's not listening for any user interaction. Check out jQuery's .on function http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably there is some element (span?  text-box?) that you want to present the subtotal in. Let's say it's a span with the id 'sub-total', then you set that items text to subtotal with just one more line:

```
$rows.each(function(index) {

    var $row = $(this);

    $row.on('input', 'change', function(){

        qty =  $row.find("td:nth-child(2) input").val();
        rate = $row.find("td:nth-child(3) input").val();            

        //convert the inputs to integers before multiplying, 
        //just to be sure
        $('#sub-total').text(parseInt(qty) * parseInt(rate));   
    });


});
```

**update based on OP fiddle**

```
var $rows = $("#tbl tbody tr");
$(".amount").attr('readonly');
$(".total").attr('readonly');

$rows.each(function(index) {

    var $row = $(this);

    $row.find('input').on('change', function(){

        var qty =  $row.find("td:nth-child(2) input").val();
        var rate = $row.find("td:nth-child(3) input").val();   

        //convert the inputs to integers before multiplying, 
        var sub = parseInt(qty) * parseFloat(rate);

        //only update the totals if the product is a number:
        if(!isNaN(sub)){

            $row.find('.total').val(sub);  

            var gTotal  = 0;

            $(".total").each(function(){
                var t = parseFloat($(this).val());
                gTotal += isNaN(t) ? 0 : t;
            });

            $('#grand_total input').val(gTotal)            
        }  
    });
});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mhfaust/Jht5j/6/)

Comment: I have a jsfiddle for it http://jsfiddle.net/Jht5j/ and nothing seems to work. May be I need a fresh pair of eyes to look into my code and fix it. I have gone blank. So if you could plz show it to me in my fiddle, that'd be great!

Comment: @user: OK, I have the script fully functioning at: http://jsfiddle.net/mhfaust/Jht5j/4/

Comment: @user: one more fix (grand-total was broken): http://jsfiddle.net/mhfaust/Jht5j/5/

Comment: You should use parseInt instead of parseFloat when dealing with the rate, and the totals. I've corrected the code and the fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/Jht5j/6/)

Answer (score 0):

When the user enters value in Qty and Rate, the subtotal and total should change in real time.

Try this,

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Jht5j/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var $rows = $("#tbl tbody tr");
$(".amount").attr('readonly');
$(".total").attr('readonly');


$("input").keyup(function(){
    if($(this).closest('td').index() == 1){
    amount = parseInt($(this).val()) * parseInt($(this).closest('td').next('td').find('input').val())
   $(this).closest("tr").find("td:nth-child(4) input").val(amount);
        $(this).closest("tr").find("td:nth-child(5) input").val(amount);
    };
     alert('');
    if($(this).closest('td').index() == 2){
    amount = parseInt($(this).val()) * parseInt($(this).closest('td').prev('td').find('input').val())
   $(this).closest("tr").find("td:nth-child(4) input").val(amount);
        $(this).closest("tr").find("td:nth-child(5) input").val(amount);
    };
    var total = 0;
    $('td:nth-child(5) input').each(function(i, val){

                                    if($(this).closest('td').attr('id') != "grand_total" && parseInt(this.value) != NaN){
                                    total += parseInt($(this).val());
                                    }
                                    });

   $('#grand_total input').val(total)

});

$rows.each(function(index) {
            $rows.children("td").each(function() { 
                qty = $("td:nth-child(2) input").val();
                rate = $("td:nth-child(3) input").val();
                amount = qty * rate;
                subtotal = amount;

                // populate respective fields
                $("td:nth-child(4) input").val(amount);
                $("td:nth-child(5) input").val(amount);
                // how to calculate grand total
            });
});
});
```